# Using golang and mgo, how do I search for a range of values in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-query, mgo

I worked through the example on the [mgo homepage](http://labix.org/mgo), but I'm struggling to find a way to query a range of values.  The line:
`searchResults, searchErr = SearchReading(bson.M{"k": key, "t": { $gte: start, $lte: end } }, limit)`
fails with:
`line67: syntax error: unexpected $`
`line67: missing type in composite literal`

I left out the non-essential bits of code...

```
type Reading struct {
    K string  "k"
    T int64   "t"
    V float64 "v"
}

func SearchReading(q interface{}, limit int) (searchResults []Reading, searchErr string) {
    searchErr = ""
    searchResults = []Reading{}
    query := func(c *mgo.Collection) error {
        fn := c.Find(q).Limit(limit).All(&searchResults)
        if limit < 0 {
            fn = c.Find(q).All(&searchResults)
        }
        return fn
    }
    search := func() error {
        return withCollection("reading", query)
    }
    err := search()
    if err != nil {
        searchErr = "Database Error"
    }
    return
}

func GetReadingsForKey(key string, start int64, end int64, limit int) (searchResults []Reading, searchErr string) {
    searchResults, searchErr = SearchReading(bson.M{"k": key, "t": { $gte: start, $lte: end } }, limit)
    return
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The line:

```
searchResults, searchErr = SearchReading(bson.M{"k": key, "t": { $gte: start, $lte: end } }, limit)
```

needs to change to:

```
searchResults, searchErr = SearchReading(bson.M{"k": key, "t": bson.M{"$gte": start, "$lte": end}}, limit)
```

Comment: Please accept your own answer to mark this question answered. You could also add a short explanation, for example, that `$gte` is interpreted as variable, which can't have a `$` at the beginning, which is why the compiler complains about the unexpected character.

Comment: Thanks, SO does not allow me to accept my own answer within two days of posting question, but will do as soon as possible