# How can I compare a float value in mongodb?

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I have a collection name myplace having place_name(string), latitude(float64) and longitude(float64). Now I have a latitude 12.34567, I need to search mongodb is this latitude is present there or not.
I tried like this but its returning null

```
 db.myplace.find({"latitude":12.3456})
```

Comment: This is the correct query presuming that the value of _latitude_ is saved a float, and not as a string.

Comment: Its float64 only, but its returning empty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is generally a bad idea to compare floating point values for equality, since the rounding that occurs in various floating point operations can cause certain values you'd expect to be equal to have slightly different values.

A better solution is to check that the difference between the two floating point values is less than a particular error margin `E`.  For this kind of query, the check becomes a range check e.g. that:

```
12.3456 - E < latitude < 12.3456 + E
```

As described [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13158335/using-golang-and-mgo-how-do-i-search-for-a-range-of-values-in-mongodb), this kind of query can be represented with mgo as:

```
lat := 12.3456
E := 0.0001
q := c.Find(bson.M{"latitude": bson.M{"$gt": lat - E, "$lt": lat + E}})
```

Answer (score 2):

First, are you looking for (have) 12.34567 or (find) 12.3456?

Floating-point numbers are an approximation of real numbers. Look for a number in a range. For example,

```
(12.34567 - 0.0001) < latitude < (12.34567 + 0.0001)
```

References:

[Floating point](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point)